# Movie involves best medical care and other privilege only for those who follow the rules

Tags: story-identification, movie

Vividly remember that a man either took a drug he was not supposed to take (forbidden?) or else refused to take a drug he was supposed to take (probably the former).

I think he was talking to his wife or girlfriend before he goes to the medicine cabinet and either takes the forbidden drug or pretends to take what he is supposed to take...

The premise was that you did not deserve the most elite health care if you did anything, whatsoever, to damage your health...at least I think that is what I remember was the reason for the strict rules. So I do not think it was about controlling emotions or keeping people artificially happy.

So, having taken the forbidden drug (if that is what he did), he suddenly finds himself whisked away either by a trap door like thing in his home or someone came to get him (seem to recall the former).

He is now in a dystopian part of the city (or maybe his own building?) for the have nots, and rather than having the best health care services in existence he is now getting the worst. I also recall that his treatment (by those he encounters) and experience in this new "area" was wildly different than what he was accustomed to. Much worse.

By the way, I have spent hours and hours over several years searching through movie database plot descriptions without any luck. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this describes the reality of healthcare in most of the world

Comment: Apart from the trapdoor, I mean

Comment: Seems reminiscent of an episode of Star Trek: Voyager titled [Critical Care](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_Care_(Star_Trek:_Voyager))

Comment: Hmm. Medicine cabinets make me think of [THX-1138](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a-SnsqKFHLY) and [Equilibrium](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raleKODYeg0)

Comment: The movie I am looking for did not have that eery flavor of THX-1138 or a gun toting protagonist as I recall.

Comment: Sounds reminiscent of Elysium https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1535108/

Comment: Yes, checked that out, but not it. I do not think the one I am looking for has military robots or is in any way militaristic. And I am pretty sure it is a lot older than 2013, but maybe not by much.

Answer (score 1):

There is a scene like this - with a few variations that vague memories could cause - in EQUILIBRIUM (2002) [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0238380/?ref_=nm_knf_i1)

Comment: OP did already state in comments that they didn't think this was the right answer